# An equivalent to the MATLAB function resample for C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I need to use Resample as in MATLAB and Octave in c++, the resample is described as below.

"Change the sample rate of x by a factor of p/q. This is performed using a polyphase algorithm. The impulse response h of the antialiasing filter is either specified or either designed with a Kaiser-windowed sinecard."

Is there an equivalent to this approach in c++?? something out of eigen or armadillo or something like that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Will be easier if you add the code, for which need equivalent

Comment: the code is basically what is explained of the function I have an array of doubles x that represents a signal that is initially sampled  at a rate q Hz, I want to resample that signal at a rate p Hz. The Matlab code is Y = RESAMPLE(X,P,Q) and in my case P is 4000 and Q is 44000

Answer (score 3):

Motorola has a [library](http://sourceforge.net/motorola/upfirdn/home/Home/) that can do polyphase resampling. Also [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) is a good general mathematical C/C++ toolkit, though I don't think it will do what you want it to straight out of the box.

Comment: thank you, that Motorola one looks promising provided I find the adequate filter.